# App not restoring bundle after returning from another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle, instance, android-savedstate

I have an app that uses google maps. I am saving the latLngBounds to variables and then to bundle to later retrieve it. My problem is that I want to save the current position of the screen and then move the camera to that LatLng. But each time when I click the marker and launch another activity and return back, the screen got centered to that clicked marker but I want to get rid of this function and make the screen return back to it's previous position.

EDIT: The problem is that my app is not recovering the data from bundle and I don't know why. Here are my methods for saving and restoring state but neither one works:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (bundle!= null){
        lat = bundle.getDouble("lat1",0);
        lon = bundle.getDouble("lon1",0);
        ne3 = bundle.getDouble("lat2",-200);
        ne4 = bundle.getDouble("lon2",-200);
        Log.d("tag","bundle is not null");
    }
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    manager.removeUpdates(this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (bundle!= null){
        lat = bundle.getDouble("lat1",0);
        lon = bundle.getDouble("lon1",0);
        ne3 = bundle.getDouble("lat2",-200);
        ne4 = bundle.getDouble("lon2",-200);
        Log.d("tag","bundle is not null");
    }
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.e("tag","calling onSave");
    if(mMap!=null){
    LatLngBounds location3 = mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
    double lat4 = location3.getCenter().latitude;
    double lon4 = location3.getCenter().longitude;
    double lat5 = location3.northeast.latitude;
    double lon5 = location3.northeast.longitude;
    bundle.putDouble("lat1", lat4);
    bundle.putDouble("lon1",lon4);
    bundle.putDouble("lat2",lat5);
    bundle.putDouble("lon2",lon5);
    }
    super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
}
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(bundle);
    if (bundle!= null){
        lat = bundle.getDouble("lat1",0);
        lon = bundle.getDouble("lon1",0);
        ne3 = bundle.getDouble("lat2",-200);
        ne4 = bundle.getDouble("lon2",-200);
        Log.d("tag","bundle is not null");
    }
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    // ... recover more data
}
```

The problem seems that the bundle is somehow null when returning from the another activity

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the map autocentered itself before launching onSavedInstanceState() so I saved the centered data that's why it wasn't working.